# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, es6-promise

I want to create a generic function using `React.memo` with return type [`list,listItems`]. Doing it this way now throws a "`TypeError`: `Object`(...) is not a function" error and I don't know why. I need feedback and suggestion to resolve this issue.I am using latest version "`react`": "^16.12.0","`react-dom`": "^16.12.0",

**Generic function**

```
   import React, { memo, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

export const useGeneric = React.memo(({
    list = [],
    handleClick,
    deleteWorkflow,
}) => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([]);

    function setImgIcon(name) {
        switch (name.toUpperCase()) {

        }

    }

    function display() {
        console.log('newItemList', list);
        setItems(list);
        let listItems = list.map(val => (
            <li
                className='block-list-workflow'
                key={val.workflowId}
                data-id={val.workflowId}
                id='2'
            >
                <Card className='wf-Card'>

                </Card>
            </li>
        ));
        setListItems(listItems);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        display();
        return () => { };
    }, []);

    return [items, listItems];
    });
```

**Main Component**

```
import React from 'react';

import { useGeneric } from './WorkflowList';
  .....
class Workflow extends React.Component {
  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.props.getAllWorkflow();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      nextProps.workflowLists !== undefined &&
      nextProps.workflowLists.workflows !== undefined
    ) {
      //   this.display(nextProps.workflowLists.workflows);
      console.log(
        'useGeneric :: ',
        useGeneric(
          nextProps.workflowLists.workflows,
          this.handleClick,
          this.deleteWorkflow
        )
      );
      const [items, listItems] = useGeneric(
        nextProps.workflowLists.workflows,
        this.handleClick,
        this.deleteWorkflow
      );
      this.setState({ items, listItems });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try use memo in main form like:

```
    const UseGeneric  = memo((list = [],handleClick,deleteWorkflow) => { 
                   //Your memo codes
    }
```

and use Generic Cmp. like

```
    <UseGeneric
        list= {//your list}
        handleClick = { //your click}
        deleteWorkflow = { // your flow}
    />
```

Comment: I checked again your code .Firstly I think you don't need React.memo because memo is imported .Just use memo.And can you move generic function on main page.I will change last answer may you should define memo like component.Try again the last answer

Comment: I  have tried all the possible solutions. but throws some exceptions.

Comment: Error change to TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Comment: I have resolved that issue.i will update the solution.

Comment: ...what was the issue?